# How to make a loop click an element and make sure that element is in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, roblox

I am trying to make my for loop normally click a certain element if it's there and I want my bot to make sure that element is there, but my code isn't working with selenium using Python.

```
driver.get("https://www.roblox.com/groups/650266/Trade#!/about")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('group-dropdown').click()
driver.find_element_by_id("role-3874587").click()

item = [driver.find_element_by_id("member-" + str(q)) for q in range(100000, 10000000000)]

for q in item:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_id("member-" + str(q))) > 0:
        driver.find_element_by_id("member-" + str(q)).click()
```

And here is the picture of what I want to click, I just want the bot to find the certain element on its own way using Selenium

[image]

Also here is another picture of what I want the bot to click for[image]

Comment: Are you just trying to get the list of members? You certainly don't need to iterate over nine billion numbers!

Comment: I am trying to get the list of the numbers that are in that specific page and click on them from that specific group section

Comment: But I can’t figure out how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of members like this

```py
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
membersDiv = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.section-content.group-members-list')
for member in membersDiv.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li'):
    print(member.get_attribute('id'))
```

Returns

```
member-1701563363
member-690819184
member-500878244
member-752963612
member-1394481071
member-389753026
member-368517467
member-1104703575
member-1641797931
```

I've added an [implicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits) because one of the elements isn't loaded immediately, you can spend more time on it and figure out which one then use an [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

The code simply gets the parent div that contains the unordered list (`ul`) and since it only contains one list, just grabs every list item (`li`) within. It's currently printing out the member ID's but you can easily change that to whatever functionality you require.

Comment: Is it possible to click each of those elements?

Comment: Yes, in the `for` loop, you can call `member.click()` as `member` is a WebElement